# Как использовать в качестве ключа обьекта свойство этого же обьекта?

Tags: javascript

Возня с контекстом не привела к успеху. world.currentTime выводит ошибку

```
      var world = {
         
   time:'night',
currentTime: world.time
         
    }
     
   console.log(world.currentTime)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, скорее всего так:

```
var world = { time: 'night' };
world.currentTime = world.time;
```

Просто мы не можем использовать сам объект при определении объекта, он же еще не создан

UPD

Можно по приколу класс сделать

```
class World{
    constructor() {
        this.time = 'night';
        this.currentTime = this.time;
    }
}

var world = new World();
console.log(world.currentTime); // night
```

Answer (score 3):

Ответ уже принят, но я добавлю. Можно использовать [геттер](https://learn.javascript.ru/property-accessors):

```js
const world = {
    time: "night",
    get currentTime() {
        return this.time;
    }
}

console.log(world.currentTime);
```